# Creating a .jks file to store Keystore in Eclipse

Tags: java, encryption, keystore

Right now I am trying to create a Java program that will be able to encrypt/decrypt data using a Secret Key. My current problems are:

1. How do I create a .jks file inside Eclipse so that any computer that runs it will automatically create the file?

   and 2, This is the code i am currently using to create a new Keystore:

   ```
   java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;
   try {
       fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("keyStoreName"); // This is where 
                                                          // the empty .jks file would go
   } finally {
       if (fis != null) {
           fis.close();
       }
   }
   keystore.load(fis, keyPassword);
   ```

Does Eclipse look in the project folder for any .jks files with the name of the String? (represented by `keyStorename`)

Comment: A program run under Eclipse looks for any relative pathname (not just keystore) in its working directory which _defaults_ to the project directory but can be changed in the applicable run/debug configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a JKS key store using the `KeyStore` class:

```
        File f = new File("test.jks");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(null, null); // you have to initialize it

        //keyStore.set...args // add what you want

        try (FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
            keyStore.store(fout, "changeit".toCharArray());
        }
```

Comment: Correct. Note that the JKS keystore has been deprecated, PKCS#12 is recommended and is the only *required* KeyStore that [Java has to support](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html). However, I'm confident that JKS keystore will continue to be supported far into the future by Oracle's JCE providers.

Comment: (@JamesKPolk) although JKS does not support SecretKey entries, only PrivateKey(+certs) and TrustedCert. JCEKS does support SecretKey, and I similarly expect will continue to be supported.